# gameobject follow mouse based on his local 2 axis unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, game-physics

I have a game object. I want to move it by mouse but only in its local space: X and Y axis. I am using `Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce` to move it in its local space.

I know that when my mouse is moving left or right, its `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")` is !=0. I know, that with Y axis it looks similar.

But I haven't idea how to use this values to move object with mouse. Is it good direction? I'm trying to do that since month, so please, help.

EDIT: Actually I don't have code, I am looking for any idea how to start. I KNOW I should move object using RelativeForce and I know I want to move it in his local space X,Y (NOT Z). I don't know how to get from mouse information about RelativeForce parameters (what should be direction, what should be speed etc.)?

Comment: Can you show some more code so that others can try to help?

Comment: "I am looking for any idea how to start" you best start by following the official tutorials and reading the documentation. it probably also wont hurt if you learn some c#.

Comment: Don't be mean, @yes. I am reading a lot and I through this month I've made a lot of not working code. Don't show you something what's wrong at the base. I am looking for someone who help me like this: 1. First think about.. 2. Second count that... etc.

Comment: Nothing mean in his comment. He's trying to  help you. If you don't have a code like you mentioned then you need to follow tutorials like he mentioned.

Comment: @user3163355 dont mistake honesty for being mean. and dont mistake the next for being mean either - if you fail at this, youll fail the rest aswell - this is superbasic². i could give you an answer where you dont need to learn and think it through, but that wont help you the slightest.

Comment: @user3163355 but since i feel bad now, lemme help you. open the documentation for both `Input.GetAxis(string)` and `Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(Vector3)` and realize that GetAxis returns a float, while AddRelativeForce takes in a vector3 as argument. Now we know, a vector3 consists of 3 floats, one for each axis and you should be able to draw conclusions yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the respective vector values by your mouse position. That's simple enough to get the ball rolling. Like so:

```
float speed = 10;

Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed ,
Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed ,
0f));
```

Comment: You can even multiply the vector: `new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("MouseX"), Input.GetAxis("MouseY"), 0f) * speed`